# Spring Boot @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have created an Entity Student and having following properties:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long studentId;
   private String studentName;
   // Setters and getters
}
```

It is generating the `studentId` like 1,2,3 and so on,that means it is incrementing the value as expected.

Now i have dropped my database `student_db` and created once again with same name. And then restart my application.Now few things i noticed here:

- Its created a student table in my database(As expected).
- Then using REST API have created an one entry. (That is created
  perfectly)

Now the issue or i don't know what it is ?

I auto generated the `studentId` from where it is was on last time, i mean `studentId` is 4. I don't know why it is happening. My expected result is `studentId` should start from 1 does not matter how many time i dropped my database. This is happening both with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

I am using following:

```
Spring Boot 2.0.0 RELEASE
MySQL 5.7.23
```

In my application.properties file i have setted

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

What i am missing here?

Comment: This is related with the MySQL itself.
You can try to truncate the table to see if this problem goes away: 
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
And run the command after to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT:
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

Answer (score 3):

This is related with the MySQL itself. 
You can try to truncate the table to see if this problem goes away:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
```

And run the command after to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,
    generator="native"
)
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "native",
    strategy = "native"
)
private Long id;
```