# @GeneratedValue is working but @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) is not working

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I tried to modify my Entity by giving automatic generation of ID. ID was generated when I place the @GeneratedValue only, but not when I gave @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) or @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO).

I use PostgreSQL.

`Location.java` class follows:

```
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer zipCode;
    private String addressLine1;
    private String addressLine2;
    private Integer countryCode;
}
```

but when I give like following, it generates values.

```
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private Integer zipCode;
    private String addressLine1;
    private String addressLine2;
    private Integer countryId;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found out the reason.

I already had an existing table in the database which is mapped for manual data population only. Now I'm trying to modify it's structure through Spring Boot, which can't be done.

Hence, I just truncated my table in the DB and error gone.

Similar way for MySQL can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784659/spring-boot-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-identity-not-working).